# Compare two cells with the same word variant

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Can anyone help me with an excel formula to look whether one cell with a string of text is the same compare to other cell with the same string of text but in different position/placement.

please see below for example:

cell A1: `apple orange grape`

cell A2: `orange grape apple`

I need a formula to check if `A1` is the same or not to `A2`

thanks

Comment: Will a user-defined function/formula do? Split function is needed, but it's available only in VBA.

Comment: are they always separated by spaces? Can you have letters rearranged or just words? Would `apple orange` match `orange plpea`?

Comment: @nutsch just words arrangement. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Put the attached code in a module and call it from your worksheet as a function, e.g.
    `=sCompare(A1,A2)`

**CODE**

```
Public Function sCompare(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Boolean
Dim vArr1, vArr2, lLoop As Long, lLoop2 As Long, bMatch As Boolean

vArr1 = Split(trim(s1), " ")
vArr2 = Split(trim(s2), " ")

If UBound(vArr1) <> UBound(vArr2) Then Exit Function

For lLoop = 0 To UBound(vArr1)
    bMatch = False
    For lLoop2 = 0 To UBound(vArr2)
        If vArr1(lLoop) = vArr2(lLoop2) Then
            bMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lLoop2

    If bMatch = False Then Exit Function
Next lLoop

sCompare = True
End Function
```